# Proving a sequence divergence using $\varepsilon $ , $N$ definition

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the sequence is divergent using $\varepsilon $ , $N$ definition. $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}n+1}{n+2}$

I am still new to this topic but what I tried :

we need to prove that for every $L$$\in R$ exists $\varepsilon \gt0$ such that for every $N \in \Bbb N$ there exists $n \gt N$ that satisfies $|a_n - L| \geq \varepsilon $.

since we have $(-1)^n$ then we need to seperate to two cases , one case where $L \lt 0$ and one where $L \geq 0$

we also need to choose a $\varepsilon$ that fulfills that so since the sequence behaves according to $\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n}$ our radius is $-1,1$ since the sequence elements are next to $-1$ and $1$ then I choose $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$
now I cannot figure out how to continue and how to prove $|a_n - L| \geq \varepsilon $ , I dont have any $L$  I only know that it can be positive or negative and I know that I have to choose my $n$ accordingly meaning $n=2N$ or $n=2N+1$

I feel lost in this topic I am trying to practice according to the rules but I feel like I am lacking understanding in it. and how should I continue from here?

Thanks for any help and tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum just added to respond to the comment/questions of Adamrk.

---

Rewrite

$$a_n = (-1)^n \left[1 - \frac{1}{n+2}\right].\tag1$$

At this point, the rewrite of $a_n$ **informally** suggests that the odd elements in the sequence go towards $(-1)$ while the even elements in the sequence go towards $(+1)$.

So, this is the point where you have to use this insight to plan your attack.  Then, you use formal steps to implement the attack.

---

One major problem, in demonstrating that the sequence is divergent is that the *supposed* limit $L$ is unspecified.  This means that you have to demonstrate that regardless of what value of $L$ is chosen, it is impossible for the sequence to converge to that value $L$.

This problem will be handled as follows:

Set $\epsilon = (1/2)$.

---

**Suppostion-1**

Suppose that it can be shown that regardless of how large $N \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ is taken, there will exist distinct values $n_1$ and $n_2$, each $> N$, such that $|a_{n_1} - a_{n_2}| > 2\epsilon = 1.$

---

Then, by the triangle inequality, regardless of what fixed value $L$ is chosen, you have that

$|L - a_{n_1}| + |L - a_{n_2}| \geq |a_{n_1} - a_{n_2}| > 2\epsilon.$

---

This means that regardless of what value of $L$ is chosen, at least one of the two terms, $|L - a_{n_1}|$ or  $|L - a_{n_2}|$ must be $> \epsilon$.

This will imply that the sequence does not converge to $L$.  Further this analysis is independent of what value of $L$ is chosen, which implies that the sequence is divergent.

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to **formally** proving that **Supposition-1** is accurate.

---

Given the rewrite in (1) above, let $N$ be any positive integer $> 10$.  
I then have to show that regardless of how large $N$ is, 
there exists distinct $n_1, n_2 > N$
such that Supposition-1 is satisfied.

From (1) above, it is immediate that the sequence of absolute values, 
$|a_1|, |a_2|, |a_3|, \cdots$, 
is strictly increasing, 
since the fraction $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+2}$ is strictly decreasing.

Given $N$, choose $n_1$ to be any odd integer $> N$. 
  Then, you have that

- $\displaystyle 1 > |a_{n_1}| > |a_N| \geq |a_{10}| = 1 - \frac{1}{12}$.
- $a_{n_1}$ is negative, because of the $(-1)^n$ factor.

Therefore, you have that
$\displaystyle -1 < a_{n_1} < \frac{-11}{12}$.

Then, choose $n_2$ to be any even integer $> N$. 
  Then, you have that

- $\displaystyle 1 > |a_{n_2}| > |a_N| \geq |a_{10}| = 1 - \frac{1}{12}$.
- $a_{n_2}$ is positive, because of the $(-1)^n$ factor.

Therefore, you have that
$\displaystyle 1 > a_{n_2} > \frac{11}{12}$.

Consequently, 
with $~\displaystyle a_{n_1} < \frac{-11}{12}$ 
and $~\displaystyle a_{n_2} > \frac{11}{12}$

you must have that $|a_{n-2} - a_{n_1}| > 1 = 2\epsilon.$

Thus, Supposition-1 is established, so the sequence is proven to be divergent.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment questions of Adamrk.

In order to understand my motive for focusing on **Supposition-1**, re $|a_{n_1} - a_{n_2}| > 1$, you first have to understand :

- What the $\epsilon$ definition is of a sequence being convergent.
- What is entailed in *negating* that $\epsilon$ definition in order to show that the sequence is *not convergent* (AKA the sequence is *divergent*).

The $\epsilon$ definition of a convergent sequence is:

- There exists a (finite) limit $L$
- Such that for all $\epsilon > 0$
- There exists an $N_\epsilon \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ 
  where the notation $N_\epsilon$ emphasizes that $N$ depends on $\epsilon$
- Such that for all $n\in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $n \geq N_\epsilon$
- $|a_n - L| < \epsilon.$

So, the above $\epsilon$ definition of convergence of a sequence is $5$ layers deep.

In order to show that a sequence is *divergent*, rather than convergent, you have to show that the *negation* of the above $\epsilon$ definition is true.  This means that you have to show that:

- For **any** (proposed) finite limit $L$
- There exists at least one value for $\epsilon > 0$
- Such that no matter how large you take $N \in \Bbb{Z^+}$
- There will exist at least one $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$
  such that $n \geq N$
- And such that $|a_n - L| \geq \epsilon.$

---

So, if you examine the formal $\epsilon$ negation of convergence, you see that given any proposed limit $L$, one is permitted to choose an $\epsilon$, based on this value of $L$ such that the above negation holds.

Instead of having $\epsilon$ depend on the value of the proposed limit $L$, I took the (valid) shortcut of **arbitrarily** setting

$\displaystyle \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}.$

The idea is that this (fixed) value of $\epsilon$ will be used in the negation, regardless of what proposed value of $L$ is chosen.  This idea simplifies proving the negation.

Then, I had to deal with the problem that I need to show that no matter what value of $L$ is (arbitrarily) considered, the sequence does not converge to that value of $L$.

---

Now, go back to the start of my answer, at the section that begins:

> **Supposition-1**

Start re-reading from that point, down to the point that ends:

> Therefore, the problem has been reduced to **formally** proving that **Supposition-1** is accurate.

This portion of my original answer, which you have just re-read, should explain the relevance of my **Supposition-1**.  I certainly agree that the definition of convergence is *convoluted*, the negation of convergence is *convoluted*, and the relevance that I attached to Supposition-1 is convoluted.

So, at this point, the question is:

Are you clear on the relevance that I attached to Supposition-1?

If not, leave a further comment, and I will respond with an Addendum-2.

There is also the auxiliary issue that you might also with to question:

Are you clear on the validity of my proof of Supposition-1?

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed explanation , just one question about the supposition , why did you do $|a_{n_2} - a_{n_1}| \gt 1$ I know it is accordingly to the definition $|an-L| \geq \varepsilon$ but I mean the idea of $|a_{n_2} - a_{n_1}| \gt 1$  where did it come from?

Comment: $|a_{n_2} - a_{n_1}| $resembles the distance of the values of the sequence if I understood right but since it goes from $-1$ to $1$ isn't $d(1,-1)=2$?  my question is what does it give us that it is greater than 1? 
thank you , and sorry for the questions as I mentioned I am having a hard time with real analysis and struggling to understand

Comment: @Adamrk See the Addendum that I just added to my answer.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! for the explanation , you proved it in a way where did not really need $L$ because it is true for all its values you just proved the inequality $|a_{n_2}-a_{n_1}| \gt 1$
In the book they solved it differently they separated into 2 cases one case where $L \lt 0$ and the other $L \geq 0$ .. 
for $L \lt 0$ they checked when $\frac {-n+1}{n+2} \lt -0.5$ after solving they got $n \gt 4$ then they solved $|a_n - L| =L -a_n \geq -a_N \geq -0.5$  for even $n$ and check the case $L \geq 0$ $\frac {n+1}{n+2} \gt 0.5$ and did the same thing so I got confused

Comment: but your way is better it is more understandable , thank you ! 
for questions like these that I need to prove divergence , can I always relay on this way?

Comment: @Adamrk The triangle inequality is always valid, so the general approach of finding $a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}$ such that $|a_{n_1} - a_{n_2}| > 2\epsilon$ should always be valid.